# Binding during ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Struggling to figure out why I am getting null returned from BindModel here. I have an attribute that is extending `ActionFilterAttribute`...

```
public class MyCachedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private IModelBinder binder = new DefaultModelBinder();
  private Type model;

  public MyCachedAttribute(Type model)
  {
     this.model = model;
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     ModelBindingContext bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
     {
        ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, model),
        ModelName = model.Name,
        ModelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState,
        ValueProvider = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider
     };

     object data = binder.BindModel(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, bindingContext);
```

The `data` at this point is `null`.

Edit: I've come back to this and realised `ModelState` is empty (so causing the `null`) because the method has no model passed in normally (hence why I am binding in this circumstance, to pick it up).

```
  [MyCached(typeof(FooViewModel))]
  public ActionResult Foo()
  {
     return PartialView(new FooViewModel());
  }
```

How can I generate the `ModelState` for the type I have, and pass it into the binder? I am trying to avoid adding the model as an input parameter, since it causes problems, but its looking like I may have to sort those problems instead if this continues being an issue.

Thanks.

Edit2: I am using an ActionFilterAttribute here to modify the model sent as response in some circumstances, and in other circumstances it accepts a model to update in the cache. In this instance I need to bind it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It looks like you want to create a custom model binder that should derive from `DefaultModelBinder` instead of creating `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: I am using the model later to store it in the cache when this attribute is used and a POST command it sent. I've cut out code to just the binding process.

Comment: If you want to do caching why not use `OutputCacheAttribute`?

Comment: Can I send the model back to the `OutputCacheAttribute`? I need to be able to keep it in sync with what the user is doing on screen, so when closed and reopened it is the same page. I had looked at this attribute before and I could not see it being able to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You should do model binding in modelbinder. Not ActionFilter. ActionFilters are for intercepting and modifying requests and responses. So, clean up your ActionResult like this.

```
public ActionResult Foo(FooViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Then create a custom model binder.

```
public class CachedModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
    object data = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    // data is not null anymore. You can do your custom stuff now, then return the model
    return data;
}
```

And register it in in `Application_Start()` in your `global.asax.cs`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(FooViewModel), new CachedModelBinder());
```

Comment: I am trying to modify the request and response, so this is a suitable attribute. The attribute is supposed to modify the model response on `GET`, and accept an updated model on `POST`.

Comment: You do a lot of work and get null when you try object data = binder.BindModel(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, bindingContext); in MyCachedAttribute. While you could just object data = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext); in the example I gave you. Now, tell me again you're doing it in the right place. I have updated my example to just bind the 'object data' you wish to bind.